# NPM can't find package even though it exists

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to run through the installation of Tailwind CSS on a Vite-based project I have, and I am running into a strange situation. I run the following command:

```bash
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
```

It tells me that `lilconfig@^2.0.6` couldn't be found:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for lilconfig@^2.0.6.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

Despite the fact that v2.0.6 is available on npmjs.com here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lilconfig/v/2.0.6

This error persists even after running `npm cache clean --force`, and I have updated npm to the latest version as of writing this: `8.18.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Devamsh Manoj for the hint. The issue was that my default registry was out-of-date. So the following command worked, where I specify the registry to use manually:

```bash
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem might be related to your internet connection. Try the same command in a different network.